# How can I append my ul from input using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo-list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Simple Todo list</h1>
    <h2>Todos</h2>
    <ul class="list">

    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="todo">
    <button>Add todo</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
$('button').on('click', () => {
    $("ul").append("<li">+ $(#todo).val()) +"</li>")
  });
```

So basically I want to add new items to the list from the input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a type error here `.append("<li">+` should be `.append("<li>"+`

Comment: Extra `(` too. `$('button').on('click', () => {  $("ul").append("<li >" + $("#todo").val() + "</li>") });`

Answer (score 1):

You had multiple errors on this line:

```
$("ul").append("<li">+ $(#todo).val()) +"</li>")
```

`"<li">` should be `"<li>"`

`$(#todo)` should be  `$("#todo")`

and last in `.val())` you have an extra `)`

final result is:

```
$("ul").append("<li>" + $("#todo").val() + "</li>")
```

Remember to not write you code faster than you can follow. Also if you're new to coding or the language take it slow and make more checks when your write so you catch problems more often so you don't end up with 3 errors in a single line.

**Demo**

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
  $("ul").append("<li>" + $("#todo").val() + "</li>")
});
```

```html
<h1>My Simple Todo list</h1>
<h2>Todos</h2>
<ul class="list">

</ul>
<input type="text" id="todo">
<button>Add todo</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Andy Hehe yer, just got a new keyboard, so everything goes wrong today :;P